# Time filter for "Highest voted tagged questions"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

In times I'm very busy with non programming stuff I can't manage to follow all the questions in my favorite tags. But actually I'd like to read the really great stuff happening in these tags the last week.

What I'm doing now is following the top users I know in my tag and see if they have any high voted answers recently, usually by crawling through the "top answerers" and "top askers" of every tag. But this is an quite annoying procedure.

Wouldn't it be nice and easy to implement to have a time filter in the "highest voted 'tag' questions" tab?

[image]

## Update

I just have seen, that what I proposed is already implemented for the main page:

[image]

But once I click on a tag, the time filter is gone. Why isn't it available for certain tags? Shouldn't it?

---

## Update 2

Regarding the comment of @Deduplicator I could search for something like:

> [tag] created:2014-11 score:5 is:question

But that is rather inconvenient. I would need to apply a certain date or I am stucked to a range of months.

Comment: Kill the useless 'frequent' tab and put this 'recent good' suggestion in its place.

Comment: There is a time-filter, if you care to ask for it. Just look at search-options.

Comment: I agree with this feature request. In fact, I was about to propose one just like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179) for this:

> [image]

There are several options, as on the homepage: today, last week, last month. You want "most votes" sort. Hopefully later this month (November) there will be saved lists, which will allow you all the power of a search, saved to a convenient place on the sidebar.

You will need to opt-in to it in your profile settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very useful feature for people who want to find out any interesting questions in the last week/ last month.

I mostly follow the `C` tag and there are around 50 questions per day. Only 1-2 go above 2 votes and are useful for later reference.

It is nice to check the highest voted tags of last week/ last month.

This is also implemented in many other sites, e.g. in https://vi.stackexchange.com.

[image: VIM]